# Angular 15 With Bootstrap 5 SCSS Utilities

Tags: css, angular, sass, bootstrap-5

I just upgraded to Angular 15 with Bootstrap 5 and none of my utility classes are working (ex: mb-3, mt-5, etc...) when including bootstrap in my styles.scss like this.

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

I know the classes have some breaking changes from 4-5 and I've updated them accordingly in my application.

I noticed when I include bootstrap in my angular.json file the utilities classes work fine.

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
                "src/styles"
              ]
            },
```

But when I remove bootstrap from my angular.json file and only include it in my styles.scss file, like below, the utilities are missing from the build?

```
/* variable over rides */
@import "variables";

/* import bootstrap */
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

/* custom css below */
```

To get the best of both worlds, I've included bootstrap for utilities in my angular.json file. Then also included bootstrap in my styles.scss file to over-ride the .scss variables, as needed. Ideally, I'd like to have utilities included in my @import of bootstrap in my styles.scss file and remove the angular.json include.

Any help with this would be great, I hate that I'm including bootstrap 2 times and I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your root *styles.scss* and remove the import from *angular.json*

```
// Bootstrap
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/helpers";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

If you have an alias for the bootstrap, please specify it accordingly